# Quick int-like type with invariant? C++

Tags: c++, user-defined-types

Is there a quick way to define a type that has an int member and an invariant in the constructor...

e.g.

```
class Age {
public:
    Age(int age) {
        Expects(0 <= age && age <= 125);
        age_ = age;
    }
private:
    int age_;
}
```

...and then have the type as usable as an int?

```
Age a1 {32};
Age a2 {40};
cout << "Combined ages: " << a1 + a1;
Age a3 = a1 * 2;
// ...etc. etc.
```

(Or is the only way to override all operators?)

Thanks, John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `operator int()` returning the value and it will be useable as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`Expects` can be spelled [`assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), and then you can expose the age via a conversion operator, which would allow all your other operations to work:

```
class Age {
public:
    Age(int a) : age_(a) {
        assert(0 <= age_ && age_ <= 125);
    }

    operator int() const { return age_; }

private:
    int age_;
};
```

---

Side-note limiting age as 125 is a bit pessimistic. Dream big!

Comment: I don't want to hijack the question, but can't `assert()` be disabled externally which then causes the check to become a no-op and would lead to broken invariants?

Comment: @user2296177 That's a feature. You test your code with the `assert`s on, and then in production you don't have to pay the cost of the checks.

Comment: Thanks! Using 'Expects' (from CPP Core Guidelines GSL library) won't affect the 'operator int()' though will it?